# Make Gantt chart using aggregation or grouping two data set

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega, kibana-7

I am making a gantt chart to display some ongoing and overlapping tasks,
My problem data is similar to this,

```
{
{hashcode=idR, operation='start', time=09-May-2023 14:08:17.900,userName='B',OperationName='abc.c'}
{hashcode=id1, operation='start', time=09-May-2023 14:08:17.925,userName='A',OperationName='abc.c'}
{hashcode=id2, operation='start', time=09-May-2023 14:08:17.927,userName='A',OperationName='def.c'}
{hashcode=id2, operation='end', time=09-May-2023 14:08:17.970,userName='A',OperationName='def.c'}
{hashcode=id1, operation='end', time=09-May-2023 14:08:17.986,userName='A',OperationName='def.c'}
}
```

My idea was to find start and end date/time from each record based on common hashcode they have.
On X axis i was thinking to put time scale and Y axis for hashcode or username.

Though i tried making some gantt chart, but i did not get any success as i was not able to club two different set in one to get start and end date in one record itself.

Can you to please provide some idea how i can achieve my goal with least load(faster) on kibana server?
We have v 7.17.7 version setup.

I made below gantt chart, where in same record i have start and end date,

[image]

But i am not sure what aggregation I should use to club two records.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to combine your dataset but one easy way would be to simply apply some transform aggregates (min, max etc) and group on your "**hashcode**" column.

[image]

```
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "min", "field": "time", "as": "start"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "time", "as": "end"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "userName", "as": "userName"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "OperationName", "as": "OperationName"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["hashcode"]
    }
  ],
```

Full spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple Gantt chart",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "hashcode": "idR",
        "operation": "start",
        "time": "2023-04-01T14:08:17.900Z",
        "userName": "B",
        "OperationName": "abc.c"
      },
      {
        "hashcode": "id1",
        "operation": "start",
        "time": "2023-04-01T14:08:17.925Z",
        "userName": "A",
        "OperationName": "abc.c"
      },
      {
        "hashcode": "id2",
        "operation": "start",
        "time": "2023-05-03T14:08:17.927Z",
        "userName": "A",
        "OperationName": "def.c"
      },
      {
        "hashcode": "id2",
        "operation": "end",
        "time": "2023-05-09T14:08:17.970Z",
        "userName": "A",
        "OperationName": "def.c"
      },
      {
        "hashcode": "id1",
        "operation": "end",
        "time": "2023-05-09T14:08:17.986Z",
        "userName": "A",
        "OperationName": "def.c"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "min", "field": "time", "as": "start"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "time", "as": "end"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "userName", "as": "userName"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "OperationName", "as": "OperationName"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["hashcode"]
    }
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "hashcode",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"title": "Hashcode"}
    },
    "x": {
      "field": "start",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"title": "Start Time", "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "grid": false}
    },
    "x2": {"field": "end"},
    "color": {
      "field": "userName",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {"title": "User Name"}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "OperationName", "type": "nominal", "title": "Operation Name"},
      {"field": "userName", "type": "nominal", "title": "User Name"},
      {"field": "start", "type": "temporal", "title": "Start Time"},
      {"field": "end", "type": "temporal", "title": "End Time"}
    ]
  },
  "config": {}
}
```